# Check for suffix if if does not exist add it

Tags: jquery, string, search

I would like to check for a .aspx suffix and if it does not exist (it is an Umbraco app so may not have it) if it does not I want to add it to my path which I get from

suppose this would be the jquery equivalent of strpos in php.

Comment: Check for a suffix in what? The URL? A string?

Comment: [`String#lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) or regex.

Comment: string from a url var pathname = window.location.pathname;

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
if (!string.match(/\.aspx$/)) {
  string+='.aspx';
}
```